# Dynamically created s3 folders are not showing in listObjects

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using signed url to upload a file from my react application to a s3 bucket. I specify the path as part of my Key and the folders are getting created properly:

```
let params = {
  Bucket: vars.aws.bucket,
  Key: `${req.body.path}/${req.body.fileName}`,
  Expires: 5000,
  ACL: 'public-read-write',
  ContentType: req.body.fileType,
 };

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, data)=>{...
```

However, when I use s3.listObject, the folders that are created this way are not getting returned. Here is my node api code:

```
const getFiles = (req, res) => {
  let params = {
    s3Params:{
      Bucket: vars.aws.bucket,
      Delimiter: '',
      Prefix: req.body.path
    }
  }
  s3.listObjects(params.s3Params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
          res.status(401).json(err);
      } else {
          res.status(200).json(data);
      }
  });
}
```

The folders that are getting created through the portal are showing in the returned object properly. Is there any attribute I need to set as part of generating the signed URL to make the folder recognized as an object?

Answer (score 1):

> *I specify the path as part of my Key and the folders are getting created properly*

Actually, they aren't.

Rule 1: The console displays a folder icon for the folder `foo` because one or more objects exists in the bucket with the prefix `foo/`.

The console appears to allow you to create "folders," but that isn't what's happening when you do that.  If you create a folder named `foo` in the console, what actually happens is that an ordinary object, zero bytes in length, with the name `foo/` is created.  Because this now means there is at least one object that exists in the bucket with the prefix `foo/`, a folder is displayed in the console (see Rule 1).

But that folder is not really a folder.  It's just a feature of the console interacting with another feature of the console.  You can actually delete the `foo/` object using the API/SDK and nothing happens, because the console till shows that folder as long as there remains at least one object in the bucket with the prefix `foo/`.  (Deleting the folder in the console sends delete requests for all objects with that prefix.  Deleting the dummy object via the API does not.)

In short, the behavior you are observing is normal.

If you set the delimiter to `/`, then the `listObjects` response will include `CommonPrefixes` -- and this is where you should be looking if you want to see "folders."  Objects ending with `/` are just the dummy objects the console creates.  `CommonPrefixes` does not depend on these.